# Two Sources Give Different Maximum RAM

Tags: linux, laptop, memory

I have an HP [1000-1205TX](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03590681) laptop (verified the model by looking at the information in the battery compartment of the laptop). The link above says that

```
 Memory Max  Upgradeable to 8 GB DDR3
```

But when I run `sudo dmidecode -t memory` following is the first part of the output.

```
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
    Error Information Handle: 0x002D
    Number Of Devices: 2
```

which indicates that Maximum capacity is 16GB. What is the correct value and why is one source saying something else?

Answer (score 2):

If the computer manufacturer states the memory is limited to 8GB, then most likely that is the limit.  A 64 bit computer can address 18.1 exabytes of memory, but no computers handle that.  The manufacturer limits the amount of memory, for a variety of reasons.  Sometimes its marketing, sometimes its cost.  A manufacturer might use a memory controller than can handle more memory, but other hardware negates that ability.